# Why can't I use docker-compose or docker-compose.exe in wsl2?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, wsl-2

I have the following bash script...

```
docker-compose build
docker-compose up -d
```

But when I run in WSL2 (Ubuntu) I see...

```
The command 'docker-compose' could not be found in this WSL 2 distro.
We recommend to activate the WSL integration in Docker Desktop settings.

For details about using Docker Desktop with WSL 2, visit:

https://docs.docker.com/go/wsl2/
```

When I run `docker-compose` I do get an error but `docker-compose.exe` I get a little further...

```
error during connect: this error may indicate that the docker daemon is not running: Get "http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.24/containers/json?all=1&filters=%7B%22label%22%3A%7B%22com.docker.compose.project%3Dnode-ecomm%22%3Atrue%7D%7D": open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

What is up?

### More Info

```
$wsl.exe -l -v
  NAME                   STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu                 Running         2
  docker-desktop         Running         2
  docker-desktop-data    Stopped         2
```

And I set the value in the Docker Desktop Client

Comment: And what did you discover when you went to https://docs.docker.com/go/wsl2/ as the message suggested? You *did* do that, yes?

Comment: Correct as far as I can tell I see the setting set in docker and I see... 

Actually see the post that will be easier.